# How to make a SignalR server only use long-polling on specific URLs?

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a server with some Web pages and RESTful APIs, and I use SignalR to actively report some status on a Web page for a better user experience. However, it seems that all the URLs exposed in this server are all using the SignalR long-polling mechanism and this keeps my API clients connection always alive, which causes some strange problems.

For example, I have the following APIS: `/A`, `/B`, `/C`. I have setup the following config so that the SignalR can work and push data from `/A`:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<PlatformNotifyHub>(
        "/A", (option) => { option.Transports = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.LongPolling; }
    );
});
```

But it seems that SignalR make all the APIs work like a long-polling one, including /B and /C in my example.

How can I fix this so that /B and /C can work like normal HTTP ones?

Comment: That API is deprecated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.signalrappbuilderextensions.usesignalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1